# Automating Killall then Killall level 9

Tags: linux, bash, shell, kill, kill-process

Sometimes I want to `killall` of a certain process, but running `killall` doesn't work. So when I try to start the process again, it fails because the previous session is still running. Then I have to tediously run `killall -9` on it. So to simplify my life, I created a `realkill` script and it goes like this:

```
PIDS=$(ps aux | grep -i "$@" | awk '{ print $2 }') # Get matching pid's.
kill $PIDS 2> /dev/null # Try to kill all pid's.
sleep 3
kill -9 $PIDS 2> /dev/null # Force quit any remaining pid's.
```

**So, Is this the best way to be doing this? In what ways can I improve this script?**

Comment: Your initial `ps aux | grep` may well pick up the running script itself, beware.

Comment: Ah yes phs, I was aware of this in advance. This is one of the reasons I put this question up. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 5):

Avoid `killall` if you can since there is not a consistent implementation across all UNIX platforms. [Proctools'](http://sourceforge.net/projects/proctools/) `pkill` and `pgrep` are preferable:

```
for procname; do
    pkill "$procname"
done

sleep 3
for procname; do
    # Why check if the process exists if you're just going to `SIGKILL` it?
    pkill -9 "$procname"
done
```

(Edit) If you have processes that are supposed to restart after being killed, you may not want to blindly kill them, so you can gather the PIDs first:

```
pids=()
for procname; do
    pids+=($(pgrep "$procname"))
done
# then proceed with `kill`
```

That said, you should really try to avoid using `SIGKILL` if you can. It does not give software a chance to clean up after itself. If a program won't quit shortly after receiving a `SIGTERM` it is probably waiting for something. Find out what it's waiting for (hardware interrupt? open file?) and fix that, and you can let it close cleanly.

Comment: I like the idea of using pkill, but perhaps change it to use pgrep with kill. That way it can also be used on a process that automatically restarts.

Answer (score 2):

Without understanding what exactly the process does, I would say it probably isn't ideal cos you may have a situation where the processes you are killing are really doing some useful shutdown/cleanup work.  Forcing it down with `kill -9` may short-circuit that work and could cause corruption if your process is in fact writing data.

Assuming there is no danger of data corruption and it's ok to short-circuit the shutdown, can you just `kill -9` the process the first time and be done with it.  Do you have access to the developers of the process you are killing to understand what is going on that might prevent the shutdown from happening?  The process might have blocked the INT and TERM for good reason.

Comment: Although it doesn't help much with directly answering the question, you definitely make good points to consider. The software in question is actually pulseaudio, and upon your advice I will see about contacting the devs about it. Unfortunately, there is a lot of "in development" software for Linux, which still makes this realkill script valuable to have.

Answer (score 2):

It is unlikely, but it is possible that in that 3 second wait, a new process could have taken over that PID and the second kill would kill it.

Comment: That would be amazing. :) Definitely a possible consideration if someone is using the script on a very busy server.