# sudo killall java not eclipse

Tags: java, linux, bash, command-line, kill

What is a good technique to "`sudo killall java`" but not the Eclipse process?

I have tried techniques where I `grep` on the classpath but everything I have tried seems messy.

Comment: All my java processes say: `15068 pts/1    Sl    52:44 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/bin/java -Xmx40M -Xms40M....` but my eclipse process says: `31210 ?        Sl     0:37 /home/x/dev/eclipse/eclipse`. So will it be a problem if you do a ps grep for java processes, get their PID and kill it?

Comment: I don't understand the close logic here? This was voted for a close because it relates to command line scripting? I don't get it? Could one of the closing parties please elaborate?

Comment: I closed it because it was a superuser.com question. But I think others selected it just as offtopic so it was not moved to superuser.com

Comment: Well, there are lots of these kinds of questions on stackoverflow. Here is just one that I dug up easily: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889425/automating-killall-then-killall-level-9. I guess all questions like this should be closed?

Comment: That's a good question. Why don't you ask this on http://meta.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest that you use `jps` to list the Java processes and then pipe the output through `grep -v` to filter out the eclipse process and `cut` to extract the pids.  Then supply those as command line arguments to `kill`.

For example:

```
jps | egrep -v "eclipse" | egrep -v "Jps" | cut -b1-6 | xargs -t kill
```

You can use `jps -l` for more accurate identification of the java processes to be killed.

Comment: Believe I have used jps before. Seem to always forget about it when I come across this problem. Good suggestion.

Comment: Thats good, thanks! I was starting to look for the memory usage to *guess* that the biggest memory usage belongs to Eclipse or NetBeans. But `jps -l` even gives the package name!!

Comment: jps | egrep -v "eclipse" | egrep -v "Jps" | cut -b1-6 | xargs -t kill

Comment: using 'jps -l' might improve this for jenkins users who are trying to filter on slave.jar. ('jps -l' outputs the full package name for the process).

Answer (score 2):

You can kill all your java process like this:

```
ps ax | grep "java" | cut -b1-06 | xargs -t kill
```

This will grep and cut PIDs of all the java processes and kill them.
If your `ps ax | grep "java"` returns eclipse too, then do a `egrep -v "eclipse"`. It will remove the lines which has eclipse. And then cut it out.

```
ps ax | grep "java" | egrep -v "eclipse" | cut -b1-06 | xargs -t kill
```

Comment: This is like the kind of thing I have been doing... Does the "ps aux" information for eclipse actually contain eclipse? Also shouldn't the kill be sudo?

Comment: If you do a `ps ax` you will get eclipse as a process too. I just tried `xargs -t kill` and it worked.

Comment: oh I see, you said eclipse is in there... yea, still don't like this approach. Have had problems with it.

Comment: You can always alias it in .bash_profile. Other wise, @Stephen C should work.

Comment: What happens if you are using "eclipse" in your classpath for another process. Oops, that process is ignored... such as eclipse jdt stuff.

Comment: Will +1 since this is a valid approach. I think first thing that pops into peoples minds but I do believe jps is better.

Comment: Sure, although I am not sure about jps installation on a vanilla ubuntu or fedora. Does it come bundled like other bash commands?

Comment: I believe it is installed with java: "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/jps"

Answer (score -2):

Use ProcExplorer where you can see process tree and you can easily get process creation time from powershell :

```
 $a =  gwmi win32_process -computername localhost | ? { $_.name -eq "java.exe" }
 $a | % { $_.ConvertToDateTime( $_.CreationDate )}
```

Comment: This is not an answer. The OP wants a solution for Linux.

Comment: What does the process creation time have to do with anything? How does this kill the Eclipse application?

Comment: Sorry for windows answer :) Your IDE usually runs for hours meanwhile your java process runs few minutes as you are developing/testing. That`s way i would work with process creation time. e.g. kill all java which is running less then 5 minutes...